# How do I ensure that data passed to Oracle SQL with TO_DATE is passed in UTC

Tags: sql, oracle, date, timezone

I am trying to insert a date that is already in GMT/ZULU time into a DATE field in a database.  How do I ensure that it stays in this format?

Comment: DATE fields don't know anything about time zones, so if you insert a date of `2017-05-31 16:08` into the field, you'll get `2017-05-31 16:08` returned (in whichever format you specify)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. DATE data type does not know anything about time zone. Value is taken as provided. Time zone will be cut even in case it is provided as TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE value.

Comment: Ok then I can just pass the ZULU time in.  That makes things much easier.  Thank you.